# How to parse such data?(parse json array)

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

help me pls . I write several arrays to a txt file, and then I want to parse them, what am I doing wrong

```
fs.readFile("./data.txt", "utf8", 
function(error,dataRes){
  console.log('Читаю данные')
  if(error) throw error; 
  data = JSON.parse('['+dataRes+']'.replace(/\]\[/g,'],['));
  console.log(data)
  createitem();
});
```

data.txt(example)

```
[{"update":"Сегодня, 14:44"},{"update":"Сегодня, 14:43"},{"update":"Сегодня, 14:31"}][{},{},{},{"link":"https://www.doska.by//msg/animals/cats/maine-coon/bdnkh.html"}]
```

Comment: You need to fix the data.txt to be valid JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is this string:

```
'['+dataRes+']'.replace(/\]\[/g,'],[')
```

The replace call is only applied to `']'`, not to `'['+dataRes+']'`. It tries to replace all occurrences of `][` in the string `']'`.

You can fix your error with parenthesis:

```
fs.readFile("./data.txt", "utf8", 
function(error,dataRes){
  console.log('Читаю данные')
  if(error) throw error; 
  data = JSON.parse(('['+dataRes+']').replace(/\]\[/g,'],['));
  console.log(data)
  createitem();
});
```

This replaces all occurrences of `][` in the string `'['+dataRes+']'`.

Example:

```js
const dataRes = `[{"update":"Сегодня, 14:44"},{"update":"Сегодня, 14:43"},{"update":"Сегодня, 14:31"}][{},{},{},{"link":"https://www.doska.by//msg/animals/cats/maine-coon/bdnkh.html"}]`;

const data = JSON.parse(('['+dataRes+']').replace(/\]\[/g,'],['));

console.log(data);
```

Comment: it really helped me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

this works but you really should fix the data.txt

```js
const dataRes = `[{"update":"Сегодня, 14:44"},{"update":"Сегодня, 14:43"},{"update":"Сегодня, 14:31"}][{},{},{},{"link":"https://www.doska.by//msg/animals/cats/maine-coon/bdnkh.html"}]`

const obj = JSON.parse(`[${dataRes.replaceAll("][","],[")}]`).flat(); // remove .flat() if you want two arrays
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: I am new to programming. I'm a little confused on what I should fix the data.txt

Comment: Don't write `[....][....]` but instead rewrite data.txt as proper JSON. Read the file, add the new data and write properly parsed JSON

Answer (score 0):

you have to fix data.txt

```
var dataTxtStr='[{"update":"Сегодня, 14:44"},{"update":"Сегодня, 14:43"},{"update":"Сегодня, 14:31"}][{},{},{},{"link":"https://www.doska.by//msg/animals/cats/maine-coon/bdnkh.html"}]';

var dataTxt= JSON.parse(dataTxtStr.replaceAll("}][{","},{"));
```